# python - code won't kill when using command to terminate

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit

I am trying to create a version of cookie clicker, except using text i/o in the console, and when the user enters the command "exit", I want it to kill the program. Still, this does not work, and it creates a new input line, except you cant type in it and the entire program is frozen. Even pressing ctrl + c (cmd + c for Mac), which normally kills the program, doesn't work either. Eventually, I just have to kill the terminal. This is my current code:

```py
import time
import random 
import threading
import os
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

cookies = 0
display_cookies = 0
cps = 74
cookies_per_click = 1
cookie_clicks = 0

all_commands = {
    "   cookie balance": "Displays the amount of cookies you have.\n",
    "   exit": "Exits the program.\n",
    "   view <item-to-view>": "Views the price (if available, otherwise, shows how to get it), item discription, and "
        "item use (if available)."
}

def reset():
    global cookies, cps, cookie_clicks, cookies_per_click
    cookies = 0
    cps = 0
    cookie_clicks = 0
    cookies_per_click = 1

def click():
    global cookies, cookies_per_click, cookie_clicks
    double_chance = ((random.random() * 100) == 28)
    if double_chance:
        cookies += (cookies_per_click * 2)
        print(f"A glitch happened. We gave you {cookies_per_click * 2} cookies, twice the amount of your cookies per "
              f"click to resolve it.")
    else: 
        cookies += cookies_per_click
        print(f"Added {cookies_per_click} cookies to your bank.")
    
    cookie_clicks += 1

def add_cps_loop():
    global cps, cookies, display_cookies

    for i in range(1):
        cookies += cps / 75
        display_cookies = int(cookies)
        time.sleep(1/1000)

    add_cps_loop()

def clear_console():
     os.system("cls")

def format_all_commands():
    all_commands_formatted = ""
    for command, desc in all_commands.items():
        all_commands_formatted += f"{command}: {desc}"
    return all_commands_formatted

def get_user_input():
    inp = input("")
    match inp:
        case "clear":
            clear_console()
        case "cookie balance":
            print(display_cookies)
        case "exit":
            sys.exit()
        case "help":
            print(format_all_commands())
        case _: 
            print("Not recognized as a command. Enter \"help\" for all available commands.")
    get_user_input()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target = add_cps_loop).start()
    threading.Thread(target = get_user_input).start()
```

I have also tried using `os._exit`, `exit`, and `quit`. None of them work. `os._exit` produces the exit error (the error that kills the code), but it still creates a newline input and freezes the program. I would appreciate any help.

## EDIT

Using @juanpa.arrivilliga's suggestion, I changed it to using a while loop, here is my updated code:

```py
    import time
    import random
    import os
    import sys
    
    cookies = 0
    display_cookies = 0
    cps = 34
    cookies_per_click = 1
    cookie_clicks = 0
    
    all_commands = {
        "   cookie balance OR cookies OR cookie bal": "Displays the amount of cookies you have.\n",
        "   exit": "Exits the program.\n",
        "   view <item-to-view>": "Views the price (if available, otherwise, shows how to get it), item discription, and "
            "item use (if available).\n",
        "   click": "Why is there a definition for this? It's pretty self-explanatory? This command clicks the cookie, "
            "duhhh!\n"
    }
    
    def reset():
        global cookies, cps, cookie_clicks, cookies_per_click
        cookies = 0
        cps = 0
        cookie_clicks = 0
        cookies_per_click = 1
        clear_console()
    
    def click():
        global cookies, cookies_per_click, cookie_clicks
        double_chance = ((random.random() * 100) == 28)
    
        if cookies_per_click == 1:
            form_of_word_cookie = "cookie"
        else:
            form_of_word_cookie = "cookies"
    
        if double_chance:
            cookies += (cookies_per_click * 2)
            print(f"A glitch happened. We gave you {cookies_per_click * 2} {form_of_word_cookie}, twice the amount of "
                  f"your cookies per click, to resolve it.")
        else: 
            cookies += cookies_per_click
            print(f"Added {cookies_per_click} {form_of_word_cookie} to your bank.")
        
        cookie_clicks += 1
    
    def add_cps_loop():
        global cps, cookies, display_cookies
    
        cookies += cps / 75
        display_cookies = int(cookies)
        time.sleep(1/1000)
    
    def clear_console():
         os.system("cls")
    
    def format_all_commands():
        all_commands_formatted = ""
        for command, desc in all_commands.items():
            all_commands_formatted += f"{command}: {desc}"
        return all_commands_formatted
    
    def get_user_input():
        inp = input("Enter your command (Enter \"help\" for all commands): ")
        match inp:
            case "clear":
                clear_console()
            case "click":
                click()
            case "cookie balance":
                print(display_cookies)
            case "cookies":
                print(cookies)
            case "cookie bal":
                print(display_cookies)
            case "exit":
                sys.exit()
            case "help":
                print(format_all_commands())
            case _: 
                print("Not recognized as a command. Enter \"help\" for all available commands.")
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        clear_console()
        #reset()
        while True:
            get_user_input()
            add_cps_loop()
```

Now this poses, another issue: the cps only gets increased every time the user enters an input, and for 34 cps, as used in the code snippet above, the cookies increases by ~0.5 cookies per user input. Is there any way to have the add_cps_loop() running constantly in the background while input is also being taken in?

Comment: It's still `Ctrl-C` on macOS. `Cmd-C` is Copy. At any rate, you are calling `add_cps_loop()` within the body of itself, creating an infinite recursion. Is that intended?

Comment: `sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)` is generally not the right approach.

Comment: If you want a loop, use a `while` loop. Python does not support tail-call optimization which makes infinite (or at least indefinite) recursion a viable option for iteration.

Comment: Historically, the control key had established uses in other operating systems before macOS or Windows existed. macOS inherited a special Command key from previous Apple II keyboards (probably added partly to avoid key conflicts, partly for branding purposes, as Command evolved from one of two apple-marked keys) that it could use for keyboard shortcuts. Microsoft, with less control over what keyboards were in use at the time, had to co-opt the control key. Later, after they managed to have a Windows key added to keyboards, it was too late to change established shortcuts like Control-C for copy.

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, that is intended, as I want it to add the CPS forever.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Then what would you say is the right approach?

Comment: @YugmShah just don't use recursion. In this case, it is trivial to just use a while loop, and more idiomatic

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Now it poses another issue where the CPS doesn't get updated. I included more information in the edit of the post